# Дефект справки "Я переосмыслил свой вопроc..."

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

> Если никто не **ответ** на ваш вопрос, то можете удалить его, никто вам не помешает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделал как и в оригинале:

> Если никто ещё не ответил на ваш вопрос,